# QIcon::pixmap(size) returns wrong size - any workaround?

Tags: c++, qt

This issue is probably a bug in Qt which I have just reposted at https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-95999 But until it gets fixed I would need any workaround. Unfortunately I cannot find any. Any ideas?

The problem is this: `QIcon::pixmap(size)` returns wrong pixmap size. And I need it to return correct size. Consider the following code:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFileIconProvider>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  QLabel image;
  QFileIconProvider provider;
  QIcon icon = provider.icon(QFileInfo("path/to/some/folder"));
  qInfo() << icon; // 256x256 is available!
  QPixmap pixmap = icon.pixmap(QSize(256, 256)); // I want it!
  qInfo() << pixmap; // I don't get it!
  image.setPixmap(pixmap);
  image.show();
  return a.exec();
}
```

It writes these lines:

```
QIcon(availableSizes[normal,Off]=(QSize(16, 16), QSize(32, 32), QSize(48, 48), QSize(256, 256)),cacheKey=0x100000000)
QPixmap(QSize(32, 32),depth=32,devicePixelRatio=1,cacheKey=0x100000001)
```

As you can see there is an available size of 256x256 but when I request pixmap of this size, it returns only pixmap of size 32x32.

What is interesting: This happens only to some folders for which I try to get their icon via `QFIleIconProvider`. I am using TortoiseGit which install some icon extensions to Windows. This problem with wrong icon size is observable only for folders which are inside Git repository. For other folders I get 256x256 icons without problems.

But regardless of this, when QIcon claims it has available size 256x256 and I request it, then I believe correct behaviour should be to return it. Therefore I consider this to be a bug in Qt rather than some obscurity caused by TortoiseGit clashing with Windows.

Btw. this is what I get by the program above - a pathetic 32x32 icon:

[image]

And this is the required icon as it can be seen as 256x256 icon in FileExplorer:

[image]

UPDATE: The same issue can be reproduced with any windows shortcut (*.lnk) file. So it is not problem with TortoiseGit.

Comment: Try to debug into the Qt code of icon.pixmap({256,256}); Maybe you get an idea what you did wrong, or how to bypass it?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and used the following code as a workaround:

```
QFileIconProvider provider;
QIcon folderIcon = provider.icon(QFileIconProvider::Folder);
QPixmap pixmap = folderIcon.pixmap(QSize(128,128)).scaledToHeight(128, Qt::SmoothTransformation);
```

Comment: But this results in pixelated icon. Just 32x32 bitmap scaled up to 128x128.